# Which windows recovery partition can I delete?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, windows-10, partitioning

[See "final update", far below after the "=====" line.] Original post:

I've been reading about partitions, and there are many ways to do things and many posts assume more knowledge than I have.

I have an HP 2-in1 with 238gb SSD. It came with win8.1 and ms upgraded me to w10. I've been using oracle's virtualbox to test ubuntu 16.04, installed with logical partition. I'm seeing some limitations in that environment compared to the dual-boot machine I set up for my wife. She doesn't use a lot of apps and has a 363 gb HD (with C:, D: oem recovery, 2 primary boot, two more recovery (260 and 838mb), and an EFI). Hers is working ok, so I'm not going to touch it, just use it for comparison.

w10's disk management output is below. I can see the C: and D: partitions in w10 explorer. I see two partitions labeled "recovery". I searched and read and watched. I can't find it now, but one hit said that one of them is for w8, and w10 adds a separate one.

**How much room** do I need for ubuntu 16.04 in a dual-boot setup?  To get more, I thought to shrink C:, but w10 disk management says I can shrink only 7.5 gb. I was thinking to keep all my data (*.odt, *.ods, music, pics) on the w10 partition, since I can see them from dual-boot ubuntu. I'm not yet comfortable replacing w10 altogether.

**Which recovery** partition belongs to w8?  **Can I delete** it?

My wife's machine has the **260mb EFI partition**, but I didn't set up vbox on that one, so I suppose that one should stay.

**Is there** a straightforward answer to my question?  A minimum/basic setup for dual-boot win10/ubuntu? A summary intro to partitions that will help me understand?

[image]

[image]

For my machine, I want to move off virtualbox and use a dual-boot.  But I'm not sure if I have enough room or where ubuntu will be installed.  I used gparted when I tried this last year, ending up with two system partitions and a data partition. But that was a slow learning curve, and I forget a lot. I want to be comfortable that I'm not going to mess something up, especially since I'm seeing different things than I saw last year on a different laptop. I want to understand what I'm seeing.

==============

**FINAL UPDATE**    I was thinking to set up a dual-boot system and was looking to recover space for it by deleting what seemed to be a redundant recovery partition.  Continuing to hunt, someone reported that ms says that the pre-w10 recovery partition(s) are not used -- but I still couldn't find out how to tell which was for my original 8.1 and which was for 10.  Someone else suggested just do a clean install of w10 and that leaves you with only 1 recovery partition. Made sense.

So I took a deep breath and backed everything up again. Put my ubuntu 16.04 iso on a usb stick. Used ms's instructions (am I going to make this up??) for doing a clean install using their Media Creation Tool: I put my current w10 on a usb stick, boot from the usb, and re-installed to the ssd (over-writes everything). Now I have only w10 on the laptop.

Following the prep steps in [this article](http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/), the next step was to shrink C: in w10's disk management. When I looked at it, the only thing I didn't understand in the new partition layout was a small 1gb partition at the left. Everything else looked normal, per articles on the subject.  So I shrunk C: (on the right side) by the recommended amount of 20gb.

Before doing the ubuntu install, I started installing and configuring my most important apps under windows, intending to have them available if I needed them after setting up the dual boot.  I wanted to get C: ready with data (*.odt, *.ods, music, pics) and main apps.  I wanted to be able to switch to w10 and keep working if something didn't work with ubuntu. This works well on my wife's dual boot machine, and it worked when I was trying Ubuntu via virtualbox (all on top of w10).

As I worked, it wasn't long before w10 did its first update. OK, understandable. After postponing it a couple times, at a break I said yes. IT TOOK 8 HOURS. I don't know if that's normal, but it finished. I continued working, alternating between prep for ubuntu and normal work using w10.

A couple days later, w10 wanted to do another update.  ???  What? So soon? Why?? OK, whatever -- I said yes.  This time it didn't take more than 1/2 an hour, but it ended with an error. Said it couldn't update the recovery partition. It gave an error code and a phone number, but it also provided a Retry button. Sometimes second attempts work, so I tried that. Similar duration, with the same error (can't update recovery) -- but this time it had this title for the window: "This PC can't run Windows 10." No error code.  No phone number. ??????

W10 still worked, so I started reading about my error and w10 update problems in general.  Turns out this isn't that rare. Complaints also focused on the fact that you can't stop the updates, which is a problem because sometimes updates break things that you've already installed. An ms rep apologized for the inconvenience and suggested that you can stop the updates on drivers -- not the problem under discussion.

A news clip reported the ms CEO saying, with dreamy emphasis, that they want to be "the...most...loved operating system". I think they've lost touch. I follow Your instructions with Your tools, and your system says that I can't use it? I've continued to use windows for the normal reason, broad application support. Why else should I use it? So that they can do what they want with *my* PC without my full knowledge and ability to stop them? Is there a law that requires them to (1) tell me *everything* they do (in plain language) and/or (2) to provide me with a way to prevent them from doing *anything* with information from *my* PC? Enough of that.

Bottom line:  I took my ubuntu 16.04 usb stick and installed it with the erase option, still following the article above.  It recommends (without explanation) *not* to use a logical partition. Contrary to its example, I included all updates and third party software in the install. Now I have only ubuntu on my machine. No more Windows. Ubuntu has been easier to work with this year compared to 2015 when I tried it before and gave up. I hope it continues to work. Otherwise I may have to pick up again on ms's problem again. Good luck to me.

Comment: Found this article: http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/recovery-partition-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-4348.html.  Says "windows can only shrink a partition from its right side, so you can tell which [one] was newly created."  I don't know what that means, so I'm a little farther ahead, but not there yet.

Comment: Final update.  I was thinking to set up a dual-boot system and was looking to recover space for it by deleting what seemed to be a redundant recovery partition.  Continuing to hunt, someone reported that ms says that the pre-w10 recovery partition is not used -- but I couldn't find out how to tell which was for 8.1 and which was for 10.  Someone else said to just do a clean install of w10 and that would leave you with only 1 recovery partition.